# Qué significa "hidden" en la consola del navegador?

Tags: javascript, consola

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resulta q aparece el "hidden" y obviamente no puedo visualizar mi trabajo,, porqué?qué debo hacer p q se comporte como antes

Comment: Consejo: Procura por favor que si vas a usar capturas de pantalla, sean de la zona específica donde se encuentra el problema ya que al momento es díficil de leer

Answer (score 2):

Esto se debe a que estas filtrando los logs de la consola. Con vaciar el input del filtro es suficiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Deberías hacer un corte y solo mostrar la zona del mensaje que la OP necesita consultar, pues ni su imagen así como la tuya son correctamnete visibles, por favor.